# What is the smallest value of $\alpha$ such that $P(X > \alpha) \ge 0.9$?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Any hints re the question below would be greatly appreciated.
I know we are dealing with $X\sim Bin(20, 0.4)$ and I know the "regular" formula $\binom{n}{x} \ p^x (1-p)^{n-x}$ to get a probability knowing $x$ but this seems to be reverse engineering the process and I can't figure out how to approach it.

**Question**

> In a large restaurant an average of $2$ out of every $5$ customers ask for water with their meal. A random sample of $20$ independent customers is selected. Find the smallest value of $\alpha$ such that $P(X > \alpha) \ge 0.9$ where the random variable $X$ represents the number of these customers who ask for water.

Comment: $P(X > \alpha) \ge 0.9$ is equivalent to $P(X\le \alpha)\le 0.1$, from which I think you can get the answer by trial and error.

Comment: Just to get to know the result: https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~mbognar/applets/bin.html .

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be trivial. The smallest  value of $\alpha$ to satisfy the condition is 0.

\begin{align*}
P(X>0) &= 1 - P(X \le 0) \\
       &= 1 - P(X=0) \\
       &= 0.99
\end{align*}

Interestingly, if the question were "Find the largest value of α such that.. " then there is no analytical solution but rather it has to be solved by computing all values of alpha until a probability of less than 0.9 appears. In that case the answer is the value of $\alpha$ just before that. If someone does know an analytical solution I'd be happy to hear about it.